# Admob Ad doesn't show

Tags: android, admob

In my android app, TEST Ad shows successfully but real Ad doesn't show .
I am getting this error in logcat:-

```
 11-02 13:14:21.129: W/Ads(6341): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
 11-02 13:14:21.133: W/Ads(6341): Failed to load ad: 0
```

Can anybody tell me why this is happening ???

My code to show Ad:

from MainActivity i called

```
     AdUtils.showAd(context);
```

then my showAd is like this:

```
public static void showAd(Context context) {
    try {
        isGooglePlayServiceAvailable = Utils.isGooglePlayServiceAvailable(context);
        if (isGooglePlayServiceAvailable) {
                showInterstitalAd(context);
            } 
         else {

        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

}

public static void showInterstitalAd(Context context) {
    try {
        final InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(context);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(Constants.INTERSTITIAL_AD_ID);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitial.show();
                }
            };
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("TEST", "Ad Mob execpt");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you created id just now? than wait for sometime.

Comment: Please post your code: how do you build the ad ? Are you testing real Ad with the emulator ?

Comment: I have tested in both emulator and real device .